# In Firebase, How to update an element in an object array within a document using Dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Here's my Firebase database
Within the "users" collection, I have a document "xyz@gmai.com. The document has an array "status". I'm trying to update one of the elements in the "status" array.

[image]

I've written the following but I would like to understand if I need to write a separate query to delete first or would this actually update the existing record or add a new record in the "status" array with the same id (1)

```
final conn = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users")
       .doc(email);
   conn.update({
     "status": FieldValue.arrayUnion([{
       "date":"10/15/2022",
       "id":1
     }]),
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, instead of `update` you can use `set` with option `merge: true` to change only the fields you specify and leave the others alone:

```
conn.set({'field': 'newValue'}, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

But in your case the code that you have written will always add a new element to the array `status` with the new data even if the `id` already exists.

One solution is to go through the existing elements in `status` array and update if you find the `id` or add a new element.

The other solution is to create a subcollection `status` and use `set` with the `id`. In this case Firestore will do the job and either create a new document or update the existing:

```
conn.collection('status').doc(1).set({'date': '10/15/2022'});
```

In both cases please remember that these operations are async so you might want to use `await`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete and add the new entry. It's very inefficient compared to how we do things in a traditional database i.e SQL UPDATE. Network calls are expensive and should be avoided. I like Peter Koltai's approach but that would force me to refactor my schema which I can't.

```
Future<void> updateReqStatus(email, id, oldDate, newDate) async {
   final conn = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users")
       .doc(email);

   conn.update({
     "status": FieldValue.arrayRemove([{
       "date":oldDate,
       "id":id
     }]),
   }).then((value) => print("value"));

   conn.update({
     "status": FieldValue.arrayUnion([{
       "date":newDate,
       "id":id
     }]),
   }).then((value) => print("value"));

 }
```